# Typescript replace generic for object keys and value

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-programming, typescript-generics

I have several code blocks that look like this. Is there any better way to do this with generics or some other typescript feature?

```
    const { authors } = book
    
    if (authors?.author) {
      if (Array.isArray(authors.author)) {
        book.authors = authors.author
      } else {
        book.authors = [authors.author]
      }
    }
```

and

```
    const { bookLinks } = book
    
    if (bookLinks?.bookLink) {
      if (Array.isArray(bookLinks.bookLink)) {
        book.bookLinks = bookLinks.bookLink
      } else {
        book.bookLinks = [bookLinks.bookLink]
      }
    }
```

I want to create a function that takes two parameters, say `('authors', 'author')` or `('bookLinks', 'bookLink')` and replace the variables, in the above code.

Comment: Is this JavaScript code or TypeScript code?  If the latter, what's the type of `book`?

Comment: Its TypeScript and the type of book is unknown, as I'm fetching from external API. 

But this pattern is repeated in several places, so I want to make this generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm following the use case, but maybe your function could look like this:

```
function fixBook<K extends PropertyKey>(
    book: any, key: K, subKey: PropertyKey
): asserts book is { [P in K]?: unknown[] } {
    if (!book) throw new Error("This is not an object"); 
    const { [key]: prop } = book;
    if (prop?.[subKey]) {
        if (Array.isArray(prop[subKey])) {
            book[key] = prop[subKey];
        } else {
            book[key] = [prop[subKey]];
        }
    } 
}
```

This should behave similarly to your above code.  It is an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), which means that after you call it, it will narrow the type of the input object so you can access its properties.

Example:

```
const book: unknown = {
    authors: { author: "A" },
    bookLinks: { bookLink: ["b", "c"] }
}
```

Here we have `book` of type `unknown`... the annotated `unknown` makes the compiler forget the actual type, so this should replicate the situation in which you get `book` from an API and don't know what type it is:

```
book.authors.author; // error! object is of type unknown
```

Now we call `fixBook()` twice. First:

```
fixBook(book, "authors", "author");
```

After that statement, `book` has been narrowed from `unknown` to `{authors?: unknown[]}`.  (Note that it's not `{authors: string[]}`, since the compiler has no idea what type `book?.authors?.author` will be.  Following the different code paths, I think after you run the function, the particular property will either be `undefined` or some array of unknown type.)  And then:

```
fixBook(book, "bookLinks", "bookLink");
```

After that statement, `book` has been narrowed further to `{authors?: unknown[]} & {bookLinks?: unknown[]}`.  We can verify by accessing the `authors` and `bookLinks` properties:

```
console.log(book.authors?.join(",")); // A
console.log(book.bookLinks?.join(",")); // b,c
```

Looks reasonable.

---

Okay, hope that helps give you some direction; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAPAQnOBrAPAaUQFNUoiwATAZ0QAUAnOAByPqgE98j2A+ACgBQiYYgBGWbAC5EAQzDsANImzdp+JVRCiu7aQ2asOOgQEppMqlUM1xORDBoBvRAG1a9pPgC6AfmnhsMDgAdzAXL0QAX0RHIREYYEQ+AEJbbBNEKAALRmDEMCI8gFF6Rno+ACIAFSyHexogqFkkOFEAKyJoCpMAbkQ44QgEKibnFxV2L2kmRiYoxABeMQkegftEvhnmHwA6F01tbi8M2JEz9aSAQVKZdh2Ha-pbzdn9rR1jk7XzkTTxo8WiC2TDeh0mqx+wmiRAANlYYt9IX8JhEli5gaCPl4IZDImtov08QIhmARsscP4wIEQkglqcRDIQNk4PQqNJnIzmfRpBVLhUogo1mkADIwKlsmLk7CiqnSFwVUQVJQVCAVCJ4olpHacrIsqjapm6+h9AD0JuIpRZyUQrQ60HqNsSHBYiACQVCAgEKAwEj4aWVOr1SsQFUD9G6q29mBwfokypFYuwVGDCokMuwEc9xOGcBhRB2MLgAHNYzgDVyqLs2nAxZUFN1eogzYhLtnSbn84WS1qE+KqzWwHWG6bzaIFBAswIgA)

Comment: That works. 
Could you please suggest a good resource or a book for advanced typescript.

The use-case, I'm just cleaning up the data from the external API, to make it proper JSON

Comment: Thank you @jcalz. I see a lot of effort went into the answer.